# Data frame to word table?

Tags: r, r-markdown

Is there a way to easily turn a data frame into a Word table via rmarkdown?

If I use rmarkdown in RStudio to create a Word document I get a nicely printed table but it is then not recognised as a Word-table. Can it be done at all?

````
   ```{r}
   name_of_df
   ```
````

Comment: I'm not sure about rmarkdown, but you can write to Word format using the rtf package: http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rtf/index.html

Answer (score 27, accepted):

**EDIT:** ReporteRs is still maintained but will not evolve anymore. Use [officer](https://davidgohel.github.io/officer/index.html) and [flextable](https://davidgohel.github.io/flextable/index.html) instead :

```
library(officer)
library(flextable)
library(magrittr)

# Create flextable object
ft <- flextable(data = mtcars) %>% 
  theme_zebra %>% 
  autofit
# See flextable in RStudio viewer
ft

# Create a temp file
tmp <- tempfile(fileext = ".docx")

# Create a docx file
read_docx() %>% 
  body_add_flextable(ft) %>% 
  print(target = tmp)

# open word document
browseURL(tmp)
```

**END EDIT**

Hi you can also try package [`ReporteRs`](http://davidgohel.github.io/ReporteRs/index.html) to turn a data.frame into a Word table, the function to do it is [`FlexTable`](http://davidgohel.github.io/ReporteRs/FlexTable.html) :

```
library(ReporteRs)
library(magrittr)

docx( ) %>% 
  addFlexTable( mtcars %>%
                  FlexTable( header.cell.props = cellProperties( background.color =  "#003366" ),
                             header.text.props = textBold( color = "white" ),
                             add.rownames = TRUE ) %>%
                  setZebraStyle( odd = "#DDDDDD", even = "#FFFFFF" ) ) %>%
  writeDoc( file = "exemple.docx" )

# open the Word document
browseURL("exemple.docx")
```

[image]

With markdown, i think this work only with HTML :

````
---
title: "HTML table"
output: html_document
---

```{r, results='asis'}
library(ReporteRs)
tabl = FlexTable( mtcars,
                  header.cell.props = cellProperties( background.color = "#003366" ),
                  header.text.props = textBold( color = "white" ),
                  add.rownames = TRUE )
tabl = setZebraStyle( tabl, odd = "#DDDDDD", even = "#FFFFFF" )
cat(as.html(tabl))
```
````

Here an other example on how to create a word document with ReporteRs :

```
library(ReporteRs)
# Create a docx object
doc = docx()
# add a document title
doc = addParagraph( doc, "A FlexTable example", stylename = "TitleDoc" )
# add a section title
doc = addTitle( doc, "How to turn a data.frame into a Word table", level = 1 )
# some text
doc = addParagraph( doc, "We use the mtcars dataset as example.", stylename = "DocDefaults" )
# add a table
MyFTable = FlexTable( data = mtcars[1:10, ], add.rownames = TRUE )
# format body content
MyFTable[3:4, "cyl"] = cellProperties( background.color = "red" )
MyFTable["Valiant", ] = cellProperties( background.color = "blue" )
doc = addFlexTable(doc, MyFTable)
# write the doc
writeDoc( doc, file = "exemple.docx" )
# open the Word doc
browseURL("exemple.docx")
```

[image]

For more example you can visit http://davidgohel.github.io/ReporteRs/word.html

Comment: why did you add the browseURL call at the end of the ReporeRs portion?  Why not open the Word document and use the table in it?  Also, using the same package, do you know how to create a title page neatly?  Thanks

Comment: The purpose of `browseURL` is only to open the Word doc from R. I add an other example with a title, if it helps.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a very low-tech (and fast) way to do it

```
source("http://michael.hahsler.net/SMU/EMIS7332/R/copytable.R")
```

and run the example

```
copytable(summary(iris))
```

now copy&paste and you are done!

Just for reference, here is also the source code for the `copytable` function:

```
library(xtable)

copytable <- function(x, ...) {
  f <- tempfile(fileext=".html")
  print(xtable(x, ...), "html", file = f)
  browseURL(f)
}
```

Comment: Could you provide the source code here in your answer instead?

Comment: @copi Just go to http://michael.hahsler.net/SMU/EMIS7332/R/copytable.R for the source code.

Comment: I did, but many organizations' Internet filtering systems block personal sites, so I thought it would be better for future readers if the complete solution was available here at Stack Overflow rather than an external site some people may not be able to access.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `rmarkdown` and `knitr` packages. Here is an example function, where `df` is the `data.frame`, `output_file` is the output file name and `output_dir` the output folder. Extra named argument are sent to `rmarkdown::render`:

````
df2word <- function(df, output_file = "table.doc", output_dir = ".", ...) {
  f <- tempfile(fileext =".Rmd" )
  cat(file = f, '```{r, echo = FALSE}
                  knitr::kable(df)
                 ```', append = TRUE)
  rmarkdown::render(f, output_file = output_file, output_dir = output_dir, ...)
  unlink(f)
  file.path(output_dir, output_file)
}

out <- df2word(mtcars)
browseURL(out)
````

Of course you can adapt the code to be more flexible.

It is though flexible enough to allow you to extract other formats too, e.g. html:

```
out <- df2word(mtcars, output_file = "table.html")
browseURL(out)
```

or pdf:

```
out <- df2word(mtcars, output_file = "table.pdf", output_format = rmarkdown::pdf_document())
browseURL(out)
```