# R file word rtf table

Tags: r, rtf

I would like to put a table in a file word with the package RTF.

My code is

```
univ_quali<-function(dataset){ print(cbind(prop.table(table(sex)), t(t(table(sex)))))}


univ_quali(sex)

 [,1] [,2]
1 0.5754717   61
2 0.4245283   45
```

I tried this

```
 addTable(rapportrtf,univ_quali(sex))
```

but it return a table like that on the word document:

```
V1                  V2
0.5754717          61
0.4245283          45
```

I would like

```
     percentage         sum
  1   0.5754717          61
  2   0.4245283          45
```

Reproductible exemple:

```
set.seed(24)
sex <- sample(c("male", "female"), 106, replace=TRUE)
```

How can i do?

Comment: You can try `ReporteRs` : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25425993/data-frame-to-word-table/25427314#25427314

Comment: Thank you for your answer but i really need to only use package rtf.

Comment: why is `dataset` a parameter in `univ_quali` if you aren't using it?

Comment: it's not true because i tried also to search.  My course doesn't explain enough.  And i finally find this one by myself!

Answer (score 0):

I finally find the answer!

```
tab_sex<-univ_quali(sex)
rownames(tab_sex)<-c("1","2")
colnames(tab_sex)<-c("Pourcentage","Somme")
addTable(rapportrtf,cbind(rownames(tab_sex),tab_sex))
```